# Call of Duty WW2 offline 2 player?

Tags: call-of-duty-ww2

Can two people on the same console play COD WW2, not in multiplayer or Nazi  zombie mode? Splitscreen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, CoD WWII supports "*Couch Co-op*", the local split screen multiplayer mode and actually a lot of that. **But only for consoles** and no more than two players. The PC version doesn't have this yet.

Currently supported game modes

- Local multiplayer (you and your pal)
- Zombies (hmm... brains)
- Online multiplayer (you and your pal together in real multiplayer)